# can not import tensorflow in pydev or the working directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pydev

I am new to python and pydev. I have tensorflow source and am able to run the example files using python3 /pathtoexamplefile.py.  I want to try to step thru the word2vec_basic.py code inside pydev. The debuger keep throwing 
    File "/Users/me/workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 45, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'

I think it has something to do with the working directory. I am able to run python3 -c 'import tensorflow' from my home directory. But, once I enter /Users/me/workspace/tensorflow, the command throws the same error, referencing the same line 45.

Can someone help me thru this part? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please add the following info to be able to help you there: screenshot of the pydev package explorer (to see how your project is structured) and the full stack trace (not only the last message).

Comment: screenshot added.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do 2 things:

1. Update to PyDev 5.4.0 and enable the support for running with the '-m' flag (in Preferences > PyDev > Run).
2. Go to your launch in Run > Run Configurations > Select the launch and change the working directory to be the project location.

Then, try to run it again. If it still fails, post your **full** stack trace... also, the screenshot for the tree shouldn't have all the source for tensorflow expanded (i.e.: I'm interested in the icons related to the project and source folders to know about how you made your PYTHONPATH configuration inside PyDev, not the internal contents of the tensorflow module).

Comment: "Select the launch and change the working directory to be the project location." I selected default of "${project_loc:/selected project name}". Is that what you meant? Now I get a simple one line dump: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4: Error while finding spec for 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials.word2vec.word2vec_basic' (<class 'ImportError'>: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow')

Comment: eclipse simply execute this line: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -u /Users/me/workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py, which works perfectly outside of eclipse in almost any directory. I tried setting the launch config working dir to a few different ones, but it always fails with ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'. What else can be different about running in eclipse vs command line?

Comment: I found the difference in how the code runs inside eclipse vs from command line. Inside eclipse, it runs all the _init_.py even those with the parent packages of the executable. When running from command line, that does not happen. How does _init_.py work? why the difference, Can I get eclipse to skip the parent package _init_.py, so it works just like from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is the entire tensorflow source tree is inside the eclipse project. Its confused whether to go to the other branches of the source tree or to the installed tensorflow modules. I created a separate pydev project with only the word2vec directory, and it now runs inside eclipse.